# android connect to nodejs

Tags: android, http-post, httpurlconnection

I have pc running node in the same wifi with development phone(i dont use virtual device).
I test nodejs server with firefox extension rested and works fine(same pc with server)
I try to post from my android app a simple json. No error thrown but no seems to work(I have a console.log() on server's .post which not shown). I have also open 8080 port. here is my android code

```
public void sendJson(View view) {

        new LongOperation().execute();


    }
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.5:8080/api");
                URLConnection urlConn;
                DataInputStream input;
                urlConn = url.openConnection();
                urlConn.setDoInput (true);
                urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
                urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
                urlConn.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
                urlConn.connect();
//Create JSONObject here
                JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                jsonParam.put("name", "kalosto");

// Send POST output.
                OutputStreamWriter printout = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConn.getOutputStream ());
                printout.write(jsonParam.toString());
                printout.flush ();
                printout.close ();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
          txt.setText(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

I change the request from post to get, from my phone browser i can access the server and the console.log be triggered but app still do nothing

Comment: Is "Executed" being returned in onPostExecute?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes its returned

Comment: @cricket_007 is there an option to tell that is "post"?

Comment: I think you are missing `urlConn.setMethod("POST")`. Alternatively, there are better libraries that exist to make POST-ing easier. Volley or OkHttp3 are the two I recommend